# npm install error from the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, backbone.js, npm

I am trying to install node in my mac..
i am getting the following error...
i downloaded the node from node site and ran that package...
can you guys tell me why i am facing that errror..when i do npm install

```
MacBook-Pro:~ Raj$ npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open '/Users/Raj/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Raj
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /Users/Raj/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Raj/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? If `npm` runs at all, it means `node` is already installed. `npm install` is for installing packages.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Running just "npm install" will look for dependencies listed in your package.json. The error you're getting says that you don't have a package.json file set up (or you're in the wrong directory).

If you're trying to install a specific package, you should use 'npm install {package name}'. See [here](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html) for more info about the command.

Otherwise, you'll need to create a [package.json](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html) file for your dependencies or go to the right directory and then run 'npm install'.

Comment: Wrong directory, ding ding ding that was my problem. Thanks @John

Comment: Wrong directory was my problem too. I had to switch to my project's root directory

Comment: I ran into this, and similar, errors because my private npm module `package.json` wasn't valid JSON.

Comment: I am in the right directory, I have `package.json` file, the JSON is valid, and I'm still getting the error...

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem when trying to run 'npm install' in a Terminal window which had been opened before installing Node.js.

Opening a new Terminal window (i.e. bash session) worked.  (Presumably this provided the correct environment variables for npm to run correctly.)

Answer (score 4):

For me I'm on windows 10 X64...

- My code `npm install` on cmd failed
- So instead of `npm` i used `Yarn`
- Just type `yarn install` instead of `npm install`
- This fixed my problem.Tried for 2 days finally found the best
  solution
- To install yarn , on cmd enter the following code
- `npm install --global yarn`
- To check if it has installed correctly enter the following code
- `yarn --version`

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was due to a bad URL (`http://` instead of `git://`, no `.git` at the end) for one of the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You're likely not in the node directory. Try switching to the directory that you unpacked node to and try running the command there.

Comment: even i went inside node directory still facing the same error

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps anyone else - my issue was a rookie error, I had a space in the name line of my package.json and it caused the dependencies to be unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this, and my issue was using an older version of node (3.X), when a newer version was required.

The error message actually suggested this as well:

```
...
Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed
...
```

So the solution may be as simple as upgrading node/npm. You can easily do this  [using nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md), the "Node Version Manager"

After you've installed `nvm`, you can install and use the latest version of node by simply running this command:

`nvm install node`

For example:

```
$ nvm install node                                                             
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.2.1/node-v8.2.1-darwin-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
Now using node v8.2.1 (npm v5.3.0)

$ node --version                                                               
v8.2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

In mac you might have downloaded and installed Node js in 
/Users/yourusername/Downloads/nodejs-todo-master  , so go here and run npm install command, no need of sudo as well., you should get output like this...

```
underscore@1.4.4 node_modules/underscore

ejs@0.8.8 node_modules/ejs

redis@0.8.6 node_modules/redis

jasmine-node@1.0.28 node_modules/jasmine-node
├── walkdir@0.0.7
├── coffee-script@1.8.0 (mkdirp@0.3.5)
├── requirejs@2.1.15
└── jasmine-reporters@1.0.1 (mkdirp@0.3.5)

express@3.0.6 node_modules/express
├── methods@0.0.1
├── fresh@0.1.0
├── range-parser@0.0.4
├── cookie-signature@0.0.1
├── buffer-crc32@0.1.1
├── cookie@0.0.5
├── commander@0.6.1
├── mkdirp@0.3.3
├── debug@2.1.0 (ms@0.6.2)
├── send@0.1.0 (mime@1.2.6)
└── connect@2.7.2 (pause@0.0.1, bytes@0.1.0, formidable@1.0.11, qs@0.5.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all because you are not in the desired directory. You need to first get into the desired directory. Mine was angular-phonecat directory. So I typed in `cd angular-phonecat` and then `npm install`.

Answer (score 1):

First download json package file from *https://github.com/npm/read-package-json*
and then run *npm install* from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

**`npm install -d --save`** worked for me. `-d` flag command force npm to install your dependencies and `--save` will save the all updated dependencies in your `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

If someone is in my situation facing this error and have tried all the above solutions, like:

- you are in the right directory
- you have a package.json file,
- the JSON is valid,
- you have tried to run %temp%
- you have tried " npm install -d --save"
  etc.

Mine worked by doing "npm install --force"

Note: This was also recommended in the error itself, which I didn't pay attention to earlier.

Even " Yarn install" worked.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you found error and it stuck while installing then try this
Open run and type %Temp% and delete all file
Then type prefetch on run app an delete all files then try it

Answer (score 0):

**These Will do the Job**

```
npm install -g yarn
yarn install
```

**or**

```
npm install --force
```

Answer (score 0):

if your organization's git repository does not allow you to install or build a project (in some git branch), you cant do anything at all in that branch.

1. **You need to checkout to a developer access branch**
   Just ask your team lead to know which one to checkout. In inteliJ, left bottom corner ,Click this to checkout.

[image]

2. Then delete you need to delete 'node_modules'.
3. Enter `npm install --force`.
4. Then `ng-serve`.

Answer (score 0):

npm install -g yarn
yarn install

**or**
npm install --force

After that, if you will get an issue you can use this command:
npm audit fix --force

Then you can install npm
**npm install**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `npm I` to install all the dependencies and `npm I express` for a particular framework or module.
Also, you can try:

```bash
npm i --save
```

Or to install it in dev dependancies:

```bash
npm i express/nodemon --save-dev
```

Here 'i' is a short form of install. Mine works

Answer (score -1):

Hey if you found error and stcuk while installing packages
,getting only three files like json file ,lock file and module file  using yarn then try this using yarn.
Open run and type %Temp% and delete all file
Then type prefetch on run app an delete all files
Then type on CMD npx create -react-app it will give you all packages